# RealmSwift - How can I store data in list

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm

I'm new in programming and I would like to know how I can store data in a List with RealmSwift.

Considering the following model:

```
import RealmSwift

class ScanResults: Object{
dynamic var id = 0
dynamic var resource = ""
dynamic var scanDate = ""
let ScanResultsDetail = List<ScanResultsDetails>()
}

class ScanResultsDetails: Object{
dynamic var scanner = ""
dynamic var result = ""
}
```

This is an example how I store new ScanResults:

```
                let newResults = ScanResults()
                newResults.id = newResults.IncrementaID()
                newResults.resource = "Test"
                newResults.scanDate = "19.01.2016"
                do{
                    try uiRealm.write({ () -> Void in
                        uiRealm.add(newResults)
                    })

                }
                catch{
                }
```

My Question is now, how can I store data in the list? I can't figure it out.. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Please, put more details. It is not clear why you can't store data in lists

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see that you append any object to `ScanResultsDetail` in your example

Here is quick example based on swift source code ([docs](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift-2.1.1/Simple/AppDelegate.swift)):

```
class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
}

class Person: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    let dogs = List<Dog>()
}

    let realm = try! Realm() // Create realm pointing to default file

    // Link objects
    let person = Person()
    person.name = "Tim"
    person.dogs.append(mydog)

    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(person)
    }
```

Comment: it is not saving data in this way

Comment: what's mydog here?